# How to initialize and customize a GMSPlace object

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, gmsplace

I want to initialize and customize a `GMSPlace` object, with a custom variable. I'm trying to do the below:

```
import Foundation
import GooglePlaces

func parseObject() {
    let parsedGMS = GMSPlace()
    parsedGMS.coordinate.latitude = 4.0 
    parsedGMS.formattedAddress = "test test"
}
```

but the issue is that these are get only properties so how can I do that ??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. [`GMSPlace`](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_place) is an immutable class. It means that once an object of this class is created, you cannot change its content. You shouldn't create your own custom objects from this class.